# this.forceUpdate() in recompose withHandler

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I want to use `this.forceUpdate()` in one of the handler named 'update' in withHandlers of my compose. I am using recompose to achieve the same. Find sample code below:

```
const abc = compose(
    withHandlers(
      update: () => () => this.forceUpdate()
    )
)
```

But it is not working. Does anyone know how to use `forceUpdate()` method of react in **withHandlers** of **recompose** library?

Is there any alternative to achieve same result as `forceUpdate()`?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `this` outside of your component's scope, so `this` is undefined.

I don't know what do you want to achieve but you should try another way to do it.

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate()

Comment: You are correct, I know scope of 'this'  is outside of my component. My question is, how to make it inside. And as I am using compose, I have one compose() and one normal function which is used with compose to make a component. Now, how do I use forceUpdate(). Can't seem to find anything about this.

Comment: @ShyamKansagra You need to declare a HOC to be used with `withHandlers`, i don't think this is what you're looking for, on what event do you want to forceUpdate ?

Comment: Earlier, when I had simple class xyz extends abc component{} structure, I had used this.forceUpdate() inside and that was working. Now I have converted my class component to compose one and just dont know how to replicate forceUpdate. As we know, all our methods which are defined in class now needs to be defined in withHandlers(). But how do we convert forceUpdate() then? That is where I am stuck at.

Comment: Not sure about this but have you tried using props instead ? Like this : `update: props => () => props.forceUpdate()`

Comment: Tried just now, not working. Says forceUpdate() is not a function. I am already passing ({ a, b}) as props. How to use forceUpdate() here? I tried {a,b}.forceUpdate(), didn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to use forceUpdate?

Answer (score 1):

There's forceUpdate in lifecycle.

We use it like this:

```
import { lifecycle } from 'recompose';

const listensForChangingModel = ( propName='model' ) => lifecycle( {
        componentDidMount() {
                this.onModelChanged = () => this.forceUpdate();

                this.props[ propName ].on( 'change', this.onModelChanged );
        },  
        componentWillUnmount() {
                this.props[ propName ].off( 'change', this.onModelChanged );
        },  
        componentDidUpdate( prevProps ) { 
                if ( prevProps[ propName ].cid !== this.props[ propName ].cid ) { 
                        prevProps[ propName ].off( 'change', this.onModelChanged );
                        this.props[ propName ].on( 'change', this.onModelChanged );
                }   
        },  
} );

export default listensForChangingModel;
```

This make a higher-order component that forces update when the model fires change event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withState` to make your own `props.forceUpdate`, since all state updaters trigger the component to re-render.

IE:

```
withState('_forceUpdate', 'forceUpdate')
```

Then call `props.forceUpdate()` wherever.